# Do Firefox Extensions run once for each tab, or run once when its opened?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox-addon

Do Firefox Extensions run once for each tab, or run once when its opened? Meaning when you open Firefox does it run then and continue to run? This would allow one to get information form one page and auto-fill it in another.

I was hoping for some info about how something like that would work (saving infromaton from one tab and auto-filling it on another).